# HTML/JS projects working independently, failing when combined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to apologize for my ignorance on this subject in advance, I am very new to this! I have two projects that work independently, but when they are combined do not. The first project is a fullPage.js project, and the second a (cursor) parallax project. The working project files are as follows:

**Cursor Parallax:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mouse Parallax Plugin Demo</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery-parallax.js"></script>


    <script>
      $( document ).mousemove( function( e ) {
        $( '.background' ).parallax( -30, e );
        $( '.cloud1' )    .parallax( 10 , e );
        $( '.cloud2' )    .parallax( 20 , e );
        $( '.cloud3' )    .parallax( 30 , e );
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>

    <style>

      body {
        padding: 0; margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .background {
        position: absolute; top: -10%; left: -10%;
        width: 120%; height: 120%;
        z-index: 1;
        font-family: Courier;
      }

      .cloud {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        width: auto; height: auto;
        z-index: 2;
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="imgs/background.jpg" alt="New York" class="background">

    <img src="imgs/BigCircles.png" alt="Clouds" class="cloud cloud1">
    <img src="imgs/mediumCircles.png" alt="Clouds" class="cloud cloud2">
    <img src="imgs/smallCircles.png" alt="Clouds" class="cloud cloud3">
  </body>
</html>
```

https://pastebin.com/bDSnQ2Nz

(for easier viewing ^)

**fullPage.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hello There.</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.fullPage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Six Caps' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" />
<style>
body{
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cloud {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: auto; height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
/* Style for our header texts
* --------------------------------------- */
h1{
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Six Caps";
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}
h2{
  font-size: 65px;
  color: #5b5a57;
  line-height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 18px 0;
  font-family: "Six Caps";
}
h3 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display";
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;

}
table {
  font-family: "Six Caps";
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;

}
td, th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}




/* Common styles
* --------------------------------------- */
img{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.section{
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrap{
  width: 1180px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;

}
.box{
  text-align: left;
  color: #5b5a57;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: "Playfair Display";

}

span {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Section 0
* --------------------------------------- */
#section0{
  padding: 60px 0;
}
#section0 img{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: url("imgs/backgroundImage.png");
}

/* Section 1
* --------------------------------------- */
#section1 img{
  position:absolute;
}
#section1 {
  background-image: url("imgs/backgroundImage.png");
  background-size: 100%;
}
#section1 .imgsContainer,
#staticImg .imgsContainer,
#section3 .imgsContainer{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -288px;
  margin-left: -636px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

#section1.moveUp .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}

#section1.moveDown .imgsContainer,
#staticImg .imgsContainer{
  top: 90%;
}

#section1.active .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}

#iphone2{
  z-index: 100;
}
#iphone2.active{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(+300px, 0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(+300px, 0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform:translate3d(+300px, 0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(+300px, 0px, 0px);
}

#section1 .box{
  top: 22%;
  left: 42%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 582px;

}

#iphone2 {
  top: -50px;
  left: -425px;
}

#iphone3 {
  top: -50px;
  left: 106px;
}

#staticImg{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 200%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 980px;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
#staticImg.moveDown{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
#staticImg.moveUp{

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#staticImg.moveDown .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}
#staticImg.moveDown img{
  top: 155px;
}

#staticImg.active .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}


#staticImg.active img{
  top: 487px;
}

.cloud {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: auto; height: auto;
  z-index: 150;
}

/* Section 2
* --------------------------------------- */
#section2 img{
  position:absolute;
}
#section2 .imgsContainer,
#staticImg .imgsContainer,
#section3 .imgsContainer{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -288px;
  margin-left: -636px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;

  -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

#section2.moveUp .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}

#section2.moveDown .imgsContainer,
#staticImg .imgsContainer{
  top: 90%;
}

#section2.active .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}

#section2 .box{
  top: 22%;
  left: 42%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 582px;
}

#iphone-yellow{
  top: -35px;
  left: -222px;
}

#iphone-red{
  top: -194px;
  left: 106px;
}

#iphone-blue{
  top: 320px;
  left: 448px;
}

#iphone-green{
  left: 106px;
  position:absolute;
}

#staticImg{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 200%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 980px;
  height: 100%;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
#staticImg.moveDown{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
#staticImg.moveUp{

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#staticImg.moveDown .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}
#staticImg.moveDown img{
  top: 155px;
}

#staticImg.active .imgsContainer{
  top: 50%;
}


#staticImg.active img{
  top: 487px;
}

/* Overwriting fullPage.js tooltip color
* --------------------------------------- */
.fp-tooltip{
  color: #AAA;
}
#fp-nav span, .fp-slidesNav span{
  border-color: #AAA;
}
#fp-nav li .active span, .fp-slidesNav .active span{
  background: #AAA;
}

</style>

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
var console = { log: function() {} };
</script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      'verticalCentered': false,
      'css3': true,
      'sectionsColor': ['#F0F2F4', '#f7f3eb', '#fff', '#fff'],
      'navigation': true,
      'navigationPosition': 'right',
      'navigationTooltips': ['fullPage.js', 'Powerful', 'Amazing', 'Simple'],

      'afterLoad': function(anchorLink, index){
        if(index == 2){
          $('#iphone3, #iphone2, #iphone4').addClass('active');
        }
      },

      'onLeave': function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        if (index == 3 && direction == 'down'){
          $('.section').eq(index -1).removeClass('moveDown').addClass('moveUp');
        }
        else if(index == 3 && direction == 'up'){
          $('.section').eq(index -1).removeClass('moveUp').addClass('moveDown');
        }

        $('#staticImg').toggleClass('active', (index == 2 && direction == 'down' ) || (index == 4 && direction == 'up'));
        $('#staticImg').toggleClass('moveDown', nextIndex == 4);
        $('#staticImg').toggleClass('moveUp', index == 4 && direction == 'up');
      }
    });
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="fullpage">
    <div id="staticImg">
      <div class="imgsContainer">
        <img src="imgs/Mockup.png" alt="iphone" id="iphone-green" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section " id="section0">
      <h1>Hello There.</h1>
      <img src="imgs/iphone1.jpg" alt="iphone" />
    </div>
    <div class="section moveDown" id="section1">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="imgsContainer">
          <img src="imgs/iphone3.png" alt="iphone" id="iphone3" />
          <img src="imgs/iphone2.png" alt="iphone" id="iphone2" />
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <h1>01.</h1>
          <h2>Some Text</h2>             
          <span>Even more text</span>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Role</th>
              <th>Year</th>
              <th>Compensation</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Sole</td>
              <td>2016-2017</td>
              <td>Volunteer</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section moveDown" id="section2">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="imgsContainer">
          <img src="imgs/iphone-yellow.png" alt="iphone" id="iphone-yellow" />
          <img src="imgs/iphone-red.png" alt="iphone" id="iphone-red" />
          <img src="imgs/iphone-blue.png" alt="iphone" id="iphone-blue" />
        </div>

        <div class="box">
          <h2>Amazing stuff</h2>
          Combining <strong>fullPage.js</strong> with your own CSS styles and animations, you will be able to create something remarkable.

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</body>

</html>
```

(For easier viewing ^)

When I try to combine them, for some reason, they do not work. In particular when it seems to fail is when I add the:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="examples.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      'verticalCentered': false,
      'css3': true,
      'sectionsColor': ['#F0F2F4', '#f7f3eb', '#fff', '#fff'],
      'navigation': true,
      'navigationPosition': 'right',
      'navigationTooltips': ['fullPage.js', 'Powerful', 'Amazing', 'Simple'],

      'afterLoad': function(anchorLink, index){
        if(index == 2){
          $('#iphone3, #iphone2, #iphone4').addClass('active');
        }
      },

      'onLeave': function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        if (index == 3 && direction == 'down'){
          $('.section').eq(index -1).removeClass('moveDown').addClass('moveUp');
        }
        else if(index == 3 && direction == 'up'){
          $('.section').eq(index -1).removeClass('moveUp').addClass('moveDown');
        }

        $('#staticImg').toggleClass('active', (index == 2 && direction == 'down' ) || (index == 4 && direction == 'up'));
        $('#staticImg').toggleClass('moveDown', nextIndex == 4);
        $('#staticImg').toggleClass('moveUp', index == 4 && direction == 'up');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

To the parallax folder, it "breaks" the parallax movement. Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated!! Thank you all!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AQs3T9dy is the fullPage.js pastebin!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That's quite a lot of code, and as such, it's a little hard to find the cause of your problem. In order for us to help you better, could you please divide and conquer to isolate your problem, and then update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: Maybe you can put your project a live server and give us the url so that we can check the code. Right now we can not see what you have inside examples.js

Comment: What does it mean that you combine them? Is there any merge of the files?

Comment: 349 lines of CSS... is sure not all relevant.

Comment: Well, first, try to separate code: styles in .css files, javascript in .js. Second, i see 2 html files, don't tell me you have combined them together, it doesn't work that way. Also, don't overuse jquery, it's a dead library.

Comment: jQuery is dead?? Why nobody told me?

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette Damn, forgot to add imho... Those who know it well are still using it i guess, but for a novice learning the library would be a waste of time, except his current job will depend on it.

Comment: @Angels: And what do you use instead ?

Comment: @MashR. I have uploaded both so that you could take a look! http://minister-memories-77328.bitballoon.com/ for the fullPage.js and http://scientist-agatha-45344.bitballoon.com/ for the parallax movement :)

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette Clean js, React apps don't need alot of DOM manipulation so im alright. :)

Comment: @PhyllisArchaleta Have a look at [the console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337).

Comment: @PhyllisArchaleta  Can you please update the combined file too where we can check the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When combining these two separate pages you should not put jQuery library twice. Include jQuery library only one. Any jQuery plugin should go after including jQuery library. If you put any jQuery plugin before jQuery library itself, it won't work.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Console clearly tells the problem: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parallax is not a function`, maybe I'm missing something, but I'm sure you haven't called:

```
<script src="jquery-parallax.js"></script>
```